# How to eliminate space between my password label and button using Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, whitespace, tkinter-entry, tkinter-button

I've attached an image below as well as my code and you can see that there's some space between the password label and the generate password button. I've tried all sorts of sizes and positions, but nothing seems to work. I'd appreciate any help. [The image of my program showing the gap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YxPvj.png)

```
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()
window.title("Password Manager")
window.config(padx=50, pady=50)

canvas = Canvas(width=200, height=200)
logo_img = PhotoImage(file="logo.png")
canvas.create_image(100, 100, image=logo_img)
canvas.grid(column=1, row=0)

website_label = Label(text="Website:")
website_label.grid(column=0, row=1)
email_label = Label(text="Email/Username:")
email_label.grid(column=0, row=2)
password_label = Label(text="Password:")
password_label.grid(column=0, row=3)

website_entry = Entry(width=35)
website_entry.grid(column=1, row=1, columnspan=2)
email_entry = Entry(width=35)
email_entry.grid(column=1, row=2, columnspan=2)
password_entry = Entry(width=17)
password_entry.grid(column=1, row=3)

generate_password_button = Button(text="Generate Password")
generate_password_button.grid(column=2, row=3)
add_button = Button(text="Add", width=30)
add_button.grid(column=1, row=4, columnspan=2)

window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean the space between the password entry box `password_entry` and the `generate_password_button`, then it is caused by the size of the canvas.  Simply put the canvas at column 0 with `columnspan=3` will fix it.  For better alignment, add `sticky="ew"` to `.grid(...)` on those entry boxes and buttons.

Below is the modified code:

```py
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()
window.title("Password Manager")
window.config(padx=50, pady=50)

canvas = Canvas(width=200, height=200)
logo_img = PhotoImage(file="logo.png")
canvas.create_image(100, 100, image=logo_img)
canvas.grid(column=0, row=0, columnspan=3) # put at column 0 with columnspan=3

website_label = Label(text="Website:")
website_label.grid(column=0, row=1)
email_label = Label(text="Email/Username:")
email_label.grid(column=0, row=2)
password_label = Label(text="Password:")
password_label.grid(column=0, row=3)

website_entry = Entry(width=35)
website_entry.grid(column=1, row=1, columnspan=2, sticky="ew") # added sticky="ew"
email_entry = Entry(width=35)
email_entry.grid(column=1, row=2, columnspan=2, sticky="ew")
password_entry = Entry(width=17)
password_entry.grid(column=1, row=3, sticky="ew")

generate_password_button = Button(text="Generate Password")
generate_password_button.grid(column=2, row=3, sticky="ew")
add_button = Button(text="Add", width=30)
add_button.grid(column=1, row=4, columnspan=2, sticky="ew")

window.mainloop()
```

Result:

[image]